# Why does this tiny RSA implementation give wrong results?

Tags: c++, c, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to implement a simple RSA encryption/decryption process, and I'm pretty sure I've got the equations around the right way. Although it doesn't seem to be printing out the correct decrypted value after the encryption. Any ideas?.

```
//test program
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int gcd(int a, int b);

int main(){
    char character = 'A'; //character that is to be encrypted


    int p = 7;
    int q = 5;
    int e = 0; // just initializing to 0, assigning actual e value in the 1st for loop 


    int n = p*q;
    int phi = (p-1)*(q-1);
    int d = 0; // " " 2nd for loop

    //---------------------------finding 'e' with phi. where "1 < e < phi(n)"
    for (int i=2; i < phi; i++){
        if (gcd(i,phi) == 1){ //if gcd is 1
            e = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    //----------------------------

    //---------------------------finding 'd' 

    for (int i = 2; i < phi; i++){
        int temp = (e*i)%phi;
        if (temp == 1){
            d = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("n:%d , e:%d , phi:%d , d:%d \n",n,e,phi,d);
    printf("\npublic key is:[%d,%d]\n",e,n);
    printf("private key is:[%d,%d]\n",d,n);

    int m = static_cast<int>(character); //converting to a number
    printf("\nconverted character num:%d\n",m);


    //Encryption part  ie. c = m^e MOD n
    int power = pow(m,e); // m^e
    int c = power%n;      // c = m^e MOD n. ie. encrypted character
    printf("\n\nEncrypted character number:%d\n",c);

    //decryption part,  ie. m = c^d MOD n
    power = pow(c,d);
    int m2 = power%n; 
    printf("\n\ndecrypted character number:%d\n",m2);


    return 0;
}

int gcd(int a, int b){
    int r;
    if (a < 0) a = -a;
    if (b < 0) b = -b;
    if (b > a) { 
        r = b; b = a; a = r;
    }
    while (b > 0) {
        r = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }
    return a;
}
```

(The prime numbers being used are 5 and 7, for the test)

Here I'm converting the character 'A' to its numeric value which is of course 65. When I encrypt this value using `c = m^e MOD n` (where m is the converted value, i.e. 65) it gives me c as 25.

Now, to reverse the process, I do  `m = c^d MOD n`, which gives me `m` as 30 ... which really isn't correct because it should be 65, no?

Where exactly have I gone wrong?

**[edit]**

Is my calculation of `d` correct?

Comment: does it work if 'e' is not zero?

Comment: the `int e = 0` there is just a dummy, e is rewritten over with the actual e value that is to be used in the first for loop

Comment: @Jay same goes for the 'int d=0', I just initialized it to 0 in the start so that I could assign the actual 'd' value later on in the second for loop

Comment: Just a remark: if this is for commercial/non-private use, please don't implement cryptographic functions yourself. The chances that some tiny overview creates a gaping security hole are quite big. In that case I'd suggest looking at the OpenSSL library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The encrypted message `m` must be less than `n`. You can't use values larger than n, because the calculations are done modulo n. In your case `m=65` and `n=35`. So you are actually getting the correct answer modulo `n`, because `65 % 35 == 30`.

Comment: @sil3nt: It's correct, but not practical when p and q are very large. Normally the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) would be used, see [Modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by having `m` greater than or equal to `n` like @interjay already answered.

But I found another problem with your code, my gcc4.1.2 compiler output `24` for the encrypted value not `25`. It is because you use `pow()` function and then convert the result (which is type double) to int that causes **precision loss**.

**Don't use `pow()` function**, instead use **[square and multiply modulo n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)** algorithm to compute `c = m^e MOD n` and `m = c^d MOD n`. It is faster than `pow()` and you won't need to unsafely downcast the result to integer.